# How to count from 10 to 1 in java

Tags: java, for-loop, decrement

For a simple Java program where I want to make the program count from 10 to 1 by incrementing of 2 or 3 or 4 how would I change this code?

```
public class ExampleFor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // 
        for(int i = 10; i > 0; i--){
            System.out.println("i = " + i);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you mean decrement if you want to count down.

Comment: Hint: `i--` means `i = i - 1`

Comment: Did any of the answers solve your problem? If so, mark it as accepted

Answer (score 7):

change the `for` loop to:

```
for (int i=10; i>0; i-=2) {
    System.out.println("i= "+i);
}
```

`i-=2` is an abbreviation for `i = i-2` 
It means that the new value of `i` will be the old value of `i` minus 2. 
`i--` is an abbreviation for `i = i-1`, which can be also written as `i-=1`

Answer (score 3):

Just use this method and give it the number to decrement with in param:

```
public static void count(int counter) {

  for(int i = 10; i > 0; i-=counter){
        System.out.println("i = " + i);
  }
}
```

For exmaple to decrement by `2` use:

```
count(2);
```

And your main will be like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    count(2);// to decrement by 2
    count(3);// to decrement by 3
    count(4);// to decrement by 4

}
```